# laravel отправка сообщения на почту через яндекс

Tags: laravel

Пытаюсь отправить сообщение на почту через Яндекс, но выбивает ошибку

```html
        MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.yandex.ru
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=*********
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=*********
MAIL_FROM_NAME=*********

mail.php
 

     'mailers' => [
            'smtp' => [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.yandex.ru'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
                'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ],
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама настройка почты

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "******@yandex.ru" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password! 1654635530-snSDjjeXrH-wnMmaw8o ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password! 1654635530-snSDjjeXrH-wnMmaw8o ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password! 1654635530-snSDjjeXrH-wnMmaw8o ".
попробовал разные вариации, но не подключается

Comment: Какой именно пароль используете? От аккаунта? Если да, то попробуйте использовать *пароль приложения*

Comment: а что за пароль приложения?

Comment: 1. Пароль случаем не содержит спец символов? Зайдите в tinker, введите `config('mail.mailers.smtp');` и сравните. 2. Вот мой рабочий конфиг для сранения `MAIL_HOST=smtp.yandex.ru
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@domain.ru
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@domain.ru
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Name`. Все остальное у вас сделано верно

Comment: Заработало, поставил пароль приложения